# Is there a way to pass ownership of a pointer in C (like in Rust)?

Tags: c, gcc, clang

I was looking for a way in C to prevent the usage of a pointer after it's ownership is passed to another function, where I can specify explicitly which parameter of a function should do that. Is there something I can use to that, like gcc attributes? I'll give you an example.

```c
void pass_ownership(/* some gcc attribute */ void *ptr) {
    // ...
}

int main() {
    void *prt = malloc(...);
    // ...
    pass_ownership(ptr);
    // After pass_ownership `ptr` cannot be used anymore
    // Compiler will throw an error if try to read/write from `ptr`
}
```

Comment: There is no concept of ownership in C, so nope. Most you can do is make it `NULL` after the function call.

Comment: C is a race car but it comes without seat belts and air bags I'm afraid :) Nor does it support RAII or smart pointers. What you are asking for is typically handled with documentation. "Don't to silly things with `ptr` once you have passed it function x" etc.

Comment: Clang has attributes for this, but that requries wrapping the pointer in a C++ class. https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#consumed-annotation-checking

Comment: You could limit the scope of the var

Comment: The usual way you do this in C is by documenting who is responsible for deallocation.

Comment: @Lundin *\*cough\* ... sanitizers ... \*cough\** Also there is `__attribute__((cleanup))` for RAII.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat All of which is mentioned in the C language standard where, more exactly?

Comment: @Lundin OP specifically asked for a GCC attribute, that's why I'm comfortable bringing up another attribute. (Also if we pretend sanitizers don't exist because they are non-standard, then the debuggers are also out. :P)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat My point is that there's a difference between the C language and the often quite excellent tool support for programs written in the C language.

Comment: @Lundin: The question is tagged [tag:gcc] and [tag:clang] so we can assume the asker is interested in those dialects in addition to, or instead of, ISO C.

Comment: C expects the _programmer_ to _know_ when to _not_ use a pointer. But, the usual is to null out the pointer variable: `#define PASS_OWNERSHIP(_fnc,_ptr) do { _fnc(_ptr); _ptr = NULL; } while (0)` Then: `PASS_OWNERSHIP(pass_ownership,ptr);` I often use this with `free`: `PASS_OWNERSHIP(free,ptr);`

Comment: You can pass ownership in C++ with smart-pointers. If C could do that Rust would be unnecessary, wouldn't it?

Comment: A few examples of C functions passing and receiving ownership: malloc, strdup, free.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin yeah, I know there is no such concept of ownership in C, my point was to know if there was something to manually invalidate the pointer after a function call. I know I could do semething like `void foo(void **ptr) { void *mine = *ptr; *ptr = NULL; // ... }` but it's just very ugly im my opinion.

Comment: if nothing can use the pointer, what's the use of the allocation? you cannot access the memory just allocated at all, nor even `free()` it, what is the use of the allocation?

Comment: @LuisColorado it's that nothing can use the pointer, if look at my snippet only the caller of `foo` will fault if it calls again `ptr`, the function has the pointer and can whatever it wants with it, like put it in a list, free it, ecc... My point was from the caller perspective, the caller should not use anymore the pointer passed, whether it will be free by `foo` or not.

Comment: I'm a physicist, IMHO nothing that cannot be observed in real world does exist actually.  If, by no means you cannot observe it, then you cannot take any information or save on it.  This is one case of such.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to pass ownership of a pointer in C (like in Rust)?

No.

> Is there something I can use to that, like gcc attributes?

No (or I am not aware of any).

The typical way is to document that the function will free the memory.

C is typically used with static analysis - cppcheck, gcc -fanalyze, etc. You might be interested in Frama-C and other annotations based static and runtime C code analysis tools.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, there's no native solution portable across compilers. However, there are different compiler features or static analysis tools.

I think it's worth being clear that they exist for those in environments where the option exists. Many if not most projects are quiet firmly tied to a particular toolchain, so if an option exists you often can grab it despite it being nonstandard. As long as it's clear suggestions aren't universal, they should be offered.

Comments by HolyBlackCat mentioned:

- [Clang attributes](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#consumed-annotation-checking)
- [gcc attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html)

The one I'm more familiar with is Microsoft's [SAL Annotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/sal-annotations?view=msvc-170). They're much cludgier than rust ownership or C++ smart pointers and not a complete substitute, but they do work with static analysis tools to prevent bugs and improve semantics. That won't help the OP based on tags, but for those writing Windows software against Microsoft's tooling it's a good one to be aware of.

#### Transfer ownership of a pointer

In general, it's common in Windows code to typedef something such as `HANDLE` to indicate something is an owned resource, and you could have `HANDLE*` (also typedef'd as `PHANDLE`) to "borrow" it without protections.

While it won't prevent you from making additional copies of the handle or having dangling references, you can improve the chance of success / semantics by using attributes that indicate you have "moved" the owned resource to another owner. E.g. consider [CloseHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-closehandle)'s header definition:

```c
WINBASEAPI
BOOL
WINAPI
CloseHandle(
    _In_ _Post_ptr_invalid_ HANDLE hObject
);
```

Because it is `_In_` a valid pointer to the resource must be passed, and `_Post_ptr_invalid_` indicates that pointer is no longer valid afterwards. In this sense then, you have transferred ownership as if you did a move on a `unqiue_ptr`.

Here it's immediately freed, but you could do the same to effectively have move semantics.

#### Disambiguate who is responsible for allocation

If we have output parameter marked `_Out_` the caller is responsible for allocating memory whereas if it's marked `_OutPtr_` the function will allocate memory, and transfer ownership to the caller via this pointer. Excerpts from [Understanding SAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/understanding-sal?view=msvc-170) in C++ but same concept works in C.

```cpp
void GoodOutCallee(_Out_ int *pInt)
{
   *pInt = 5;
}

void OutCaller()
{
   int *pInt = new int;
   GoodOutCallee(pInt);
   delete pInt;
}

void GoodOutPtrCallee(_Outptr_ int **pInt)
{
   int *pInt2 = new int;
   *pInt2 = 5;

   *pInt = pInt2;
}

void OutPtrCaller()
{
   int *pInt = NULL;
   GoodOutPtrCallee(&pInt);
   delete pInt;
}
```

#### Further Topics

When you're working with a `char *`, what actually is it? A pointer to a character, the start of character array, or a null-terminated c-string?

There are annotations for null possible / optional, and also annotations to [formally specify requirements around buffer links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/understanding-sal?view=msvc-170#sal-makes-code-more-valuable) that are much clearer than comments, and if you run static analysis can automatically catch buffer overruns that are potential security issues.

E.g. making memcpy requirements explicit:

```c
void * memcpy(
   _Out_writes_bytes_all_(count) void *dest,
   _In_reads_bytes_(count) const void *src,
   size_t count
);
```

Comment: `__cleanup__` doesn't help with this, I only mentioned it in off-topic discussion. I think the answer would benefit from some code samples of how it could be achieved with Clang attribs or MS annotations.

Comment: Yeah in retrospect I'll drop that one. I was meaning to highlight that options get you closer to C++ / Rust concepts in general, but that's not clear as is. I'll add a SAL example for the partial solution it offers, though someone else hopefully will give a clang one. Every time I've used clang it's for C++ and thus just used smart pointers.